# Python sorting by alphabetically by name, suffix and length

Tags: python, sorting

I've been trying to get a list of metals sorted alphabetically by name, suffix and length but can only seem to sort by length. I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

**metals.csv**

```
list of names with date and suffix
name,date,suffix
copper.abc,2017-10-06,abc
gold.xyz,2017-10-06,xyz
19823.efg,2017-10-06,efg
silver.abc,2017-10-06,abc
iron.efg,2017-10-06,efg
unknown9258.xyz,2017-10-06,xyz
nickel.xyz,2017-10-06,xyz
bronze.abc,2017-10-06,abc
platinum.abc,2017-10-06,abc
unknown--23.efg,2017-10-06,efg
```

**filter_sort.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import enchant
import re
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter

pattern = re.compile(u"([^0-9-]+\..*),(.*,.*)", flags=re.UNICODE)

original = open('metals.csv', 'r')
with open('output.txt', 'a') as newfile:
    for line in original.readlines():
        m = pattern.match(line)
        if m:
            repl = m.group(1)
            newfile.write(m.group(1)+"\n")
newfile.close()

d = enchant.Dict("en_US")

output = []

infile = open("output.txt", "r")
with open('filtered.txt', 'a') as filtered:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        word = line.strip('\n').split('.')[0]
        if d.check(word) is True:
            if len(word) <= 8:
                output.append("{0}.{1}".format(word, line.strip('\n').split('.')[1]))
    for name in sorted(output, key=len):
        filtered.write(str(name+"\n"))
filtered.close()
```

The result is:

```
gold.xyz
iron.efg
copper.abc
silver.abc
nickel.xyz
bronze.abc
platinum.abc
```

I would like to have:

```
bronze.abc
copper.abc
silver.abc
platinum.abc
iron.efg
gold.xyz
nickel.xyz
```

I first take a list and filter out names with digits or dashes then save it to a new file. Next I attempt to sort the resulting list and save it again to a new list. I'm not that familiar with Python so it's obviously and most likely inefficient. Any tips would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: What are your sorting priorities? First by suffix alphabetically, Then by prefix alphabetically and then by length?

Comment: @DanielTrugman: Yes, that is precisely it. It might be nice to be able to switch them around as needed, but just an idea of how to include all three would be helpful.

Comment: @ctfd, your code could be reduced twice (refactored) i.e. optimized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You request the sort to use your length as the key:

```
for name in sorted(output, key=len):
```

Instead sort your dictionary using a lambda that returns a tuple like so:

```
for name in sorted(output, key=lambda k: (k.split('.')[1], k.split('.')[0], len)):
```

Sorts first according to the suffix (e.g. abc), then the prefix (e.g. bronze) and last by len. Outputs:

```
bronze.abc
copper.abc
silver.abc
platinum.abc
iron.efg
gold.xyz
nickel.xyz
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would i sort/group the suffixes and length also? This only seems to sort alphabetically.

Comment: You just need to implement the key function to return a tuple with all conditions you wanna use to sort your list.

Comment: @DanielTrugman: Change your answer to read `for name in sorted(output, key=lambda k: (k.split('.')[1], k.split('.')[0], len)):` and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Complete optimized solution:

```
import csv, re

def multi_sort(s):
    parts = s.split('.')
    return (parts[1], len(s), parts[0])

with open('metals.csv', 'r') as inp, open('output.txt', 'w', newline='') as out:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inp, fieldnames=None)  # name,date,suffix - header line
    names = []
    for l in reader:
        if re.search(r'[^0-9-]+\..*', l['name']):
            names.append(l['name'])
    names.sort(key=multi_sort)

    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for n in names:
        writer.writerow((n,))
```

The `output.txt` contents:

```
bronze.abc
copper.abc
silver.abc
platinum.abc
iron.efg
gold.xyz
nickel.xyz
```

Comment: Thank you, I get `TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function` - not sure exactly why?

Comment: @ctfd, mostly because you are using an old Python version. That's for 3.x. You may remove `newline` attr

Comment: Ah okay, I'm sorry that I didn't specify that it was Python 2.7. I'll upvote your answer though for answering, thanks!

Comment: @ctfd, you could at least try to apply this solution which is much shorter